# rt73.bin for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, ralink

I have a D-Link USB WLAN stick and want to install Ubuntu 12.04 alternate. The installer asks me to insert an exchangable drive containing 'rt73.bin', the driver. I cannot find any binary downloads, but cannot build the package, because I have no other linux PC. What can I do?

//EDIT: The reason why I want to do this during setup is that I want to setup an LTSP server. I only found guides that assume one has Internet connection - but I have not. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file rt73.bin is the needed firmware for the driver rt73usb, both of which are installed by default in 12.04. rt73.bin should be in /lib/firmware. If you don't have it and need it, here is a Dropbox link and you can transfer it on a USB key or similar.   https://dl.dropbox.com/u/58267392/rt73.zip

Comment: Should the Dropbox link get deactivated (they do this to high-traffic links), here an alternative (unfortunately with advertisements): http://www.filedropper.com/rt73