# Wifi adapter worked from 12.04 DVD but won't connect after installing UB 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, network-manager

I really don't get it, my wifi worked fine when I booted from dvd but after installing ub 12.04 my wifi only detects all APs but I suddenly can't connect to any of 'm and my neighbor upstairs and me are sharing his broadband connection (So I can only connect to the internet via Wifi and not by cable)

I'm so pissed off, I donated $25 when I was asked for a donation before downloading ub 12.04, because of the "good" first impression I got from the trial I thought, why not, it works fine
Which it DID until I installed ub 12.04 and got stuck, I'm writing this on a damn tablet, ain't that great?
How can I download necessary drivers if I can't get my pc connected?

I have a sweex rt73 and a built in wifi adapter Ralink technology corp 802.11n wireless lan card, but i'd rather not use the built in card because I have a much better signal on the sweex rt73 wifi stick

I also tried tethering my pc with a tablet but after a few seconds ub disconnects the usb connection to the tablet, so no network there either

Comment: I installed windows again and here's the info on my wifi adapters: 9sry for the messy looking list but for some reason i cannot start a new line by pressing enter. When I press enter my comment gets posted rightaway and I am only allowed to edit) Built in netw card: 802.11n Wireless LAN Card
PCI\VEN_1814&DEV_3062
PCI bus 5, device 5, function 0
Ralink Technology, Corp.
Usb wifi stick:
RT73 USB Wireless LAN Card
USB\VID_148F&PID_2573
Port_#0002.Hub_#0007
Ralink Technology Corp.
To me it doesn't look really useful, but what do I know, right?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the drivers for your two devices are conflicting. I suggest you blacklist the driver for the internal device. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rt2800pci"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r rt2800pci
exit
```

The RT73 device may work perfectly now; if not, check the logs for useful clues:

```
dmesg | grep rt7
```

If it complains about missing firmware, please check here: [rt73.bin for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229562/rt73-bin-for-ubuntu-12-04-lts/)

Comment: tHANKS, i'LL DO THAT WHEN i CAN BOOT THE uB PARTITION (sry caps). Suddenly I can't boot UB anymore. Bios sees the UB drive in post but I can't set it as Boot drive. It's a 2.3 TB drive. When I press F11 during post it's not listed as potential boot device. When I know where i want to install UB again, a workaround is making 2 partitions on 2.3 TB drive, I didn't buy a high volume storage device to partition it as 2 much cheaper <2.0 TB HDDs. I'll post results but it may take a while, RL obligations. I spent 3 days to get PC back to before it went nuts, I feel like gaming. But " I'll be back"

Comment: We'll be here to help when you're ready!